# When I use jpql like `:label in elements(labels)` in hibernate, there is an exception

Tags: java, hibernate, ninjaframework

The framework I am using is `ninjaframework 6.9.0` and `hibernate 5.6.7`,and `Guice` used by this framework.

It is java17, The database is postgresql 14.2.

I have a model like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data")

public class Data {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;

     @Column(name = "labels")
     @Type(type = "com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType")
     private String[] labels;

}
```

I query using a query statement like this:

```
String queryString = "FROM Data data WHERE :label in elements(data.labels) ";
TypedQuery<Data> dataTypeQuery = entityManager.createQuery(queryString,Data.class);
dataTypeQuery.setParameter("label","aLabel");
List<Data> dataList = dataTypeQuery.getResultList();
```

I will get an exception at `entityManager.createQuery()`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.persister.collection.QueryableCollection.getElementPersister()" because "queryableCollection" is null
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode.resolveCollectionProperty(MethodNode.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.CollectionFunction.resolve(CollectionFunction.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processFunction(HqlSqlWalker.java:1253)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.collectionFunction(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3132)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.collectionFunctionOrSubselect(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5012)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.inRhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4919)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4578)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2180)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2108)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:841)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:635)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:339)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:848)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at mag.beanbot.qqepipeline.dao.QqeTeacherDao.findByDate(QqeTeacherDao.java:100)
    at mag.beanbot.schedulesearcher.service.SsTeacherScheduleService.findScheduleByDateV2(SsTeacherScheduleService.java:455)
    at ninja.jpa.UnitOfWorkInterceptor.invoke(UnitOfWorkInterceptor.java:66)
    at mag.beanbot.schedulesearcher.controller.ScheduleSearcherController.timeSearch(ScheduleSearcherController.java:181)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at ninja.params.ControllerMethodInvoker.invoke(ControllerMethodInvoker.java:76)
    at ninja.FilterChainEnd.next(FilterChainEnd.java:45)
    at filters.LoggerFilter.filter(LoggerFilter.java:49)
    at ninja.FilterChainImpl.next(FilterChainImpl.java:36)
    at ninja.NinjaDefault.onRouteRequest(NinjaDefault.java:112)
    at ninja.servlet.NinjaServletDispatcher.service(NinjaServletDispatcher.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:290)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:280)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:184)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:121)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:133)
    at ninja.servlet.NinjaServletFilter.doFilter(NinjaServletFilter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I'm not sure what's going on. I tried with different hibernate versions, still doesn't work. model is normal.
Is it an error in the query statement?

Below is the pom.xml for hibernate.
ninjaframework is hibernate version 3.4, I upgraded it to 5.6.7.

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, it is java17, the database is postgresql